# left align a cell contents in html table

Tags: html, vba

I am sending an e-mail from Excel using Outlook. I am sending the message as an html message. The message sends but not in the format I expect. The headers are fine but the cells below do not left align as I expect.

How do I get the cells below the header to be left aligned? I thought by using the align attribute it should be fine?

My code

```
Private Function CreateHTMLMsg() As String

Dim msg As String
Dim colourMkt As String
Dim colourBid As String
Dim colourAsk As String
Dim i As Integer

msg = "<table style='font-size: 12pt;'><tr></tr><tr><th align='left'>Fund</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" & _
    "<th align='left'>Mkt Spread</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" & _
    "<th align='left'>Bid Spread</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" & _
    "<th align='left'>Ask Spread</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>"

For i = 1 To UBound(pBreaches)
If pBreaches(i).SendEmail = True Then

    If pBreaches(i).BreachedMkt = True Then
        colourMkt = "yellow"
    Else
        colourMkt = "transparent"
    End If
    If pBreaches(i).BreachedBid = True Then
        colourBid = "yellow"
    Else
        colourBid = "transparent"
    End If
    If pBreaches(i).BreachedAsk = True Then
        colourAsk = "yellow"
    Else
        colourAsk = "transparent"
    End If

    msg = msg & "<tr style='font-size: 10pt;'><td>" & pBreaches(i).Fund & "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>" & _
                "<td align='left' style='background-color:" & colourMkt & "'>" & pBreaches(i).SpreadMkt & "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>" & _
                "<td align='left' style='background-color:" & colourBid & "'>" & pBreaches(i).SpreadBid & "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>" & _
                "<td align='left' style='background-color:" & colourAsk & "'>" & pBreaches(i).SpreadAsk & "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td></tr>"
End If
Next i

CreateHTMLMsg = msg & "</table>"

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with :

```
style="float: left;" (HTML)
float: left; (CSS)
```

Here is more infos about HTML table and CSS about it : [Complete Guide to the Table element](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/)

Comment: no still doesn't seem to do anything. had "<td float: left; style='background-color:" & colourMkt & "'>" & pBreaches(i).SpreadMkt & "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>"

Comment: `float: left;` should be included in style tag:
<td style='float: left; background-color:" & colourMkt & "'>" & pBreaches(i).SpreadMkt & "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>

Comment: It looks strange.. Take a look at the link above. I'll take a look later, I also got a problem :p
EDIT : Yeah Mielk ! I didn't notice that mistake !